# Unable to access remote WCF web service hosted on server

Tags: wcf, iis-7, vb.net-2010

Hi I have deployed the WCF web service on the server machine. I am able to browse it in browser. but when i am going to add its service reference to my web application on development machine I am getting following detail error:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://ServerMachineName:500/ITCAMSWebService_deploy/Services/Authentication.svc?wsdl'.
>       The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
>       There was an error downloading 'http://ServerMachineName:500/ITCAMSWebService_deploy/Services/Authentication.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
>       The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>       Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>       An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>       Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://ServerMachineName:500/ITCAMSWebService_deploy/Services/Authentication.svc'.
>       Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service
>   `http://ServerMachineName:500/ITCAMSWebService_deploy/Services/Authentication.svc`.
>   The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
>       The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
>   was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
>       If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Generated Service Model section in Web.config at server is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <services>
          <service name="Authentication" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior_Authentication">
              <host>
                  <baseAddresses>
                      <add baseAddress="http://ServerMachineName:500/ITCAMSWebService_deploy/Services/Authentication.svc"></add>
                  </baseAddresses>
              </host>
              <endpoint address="" contract="IAuthentication" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ITCAMSWebService.IAuthentication" />

          </service>
      </services>
    <behaviors>


      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>


    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: If you have access to the server, enable tracing in the config of the wcf service. It will tell you exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved !!! By adding `Everyone` user with full rights to C:\Windows\Temp on the server. IIS needs the rights to generate Metadata file in Temp folder on the server.

Comment: Actually you only need to give write permissions to IIS (IIS_USERS) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4120815/96505. But giving full access to everyone, on a development machine, does the job

Answer (score 0):

Please give ip address of your server in the address instead of ServerMachineName and also check the bindings of both client n server

Comment: check the bindings you have given in server... basicHttpBinding or WsHttpBinding?  The same should be given to the client

Comment: I edited my question with web.config. I am new in WCF deployment. What need to be add in this section ?

Comment: how could same on both client ans server ? its avoiding me to add reference to web application itself. so nothing generating in web application web.config. please guide